# has_one :through doesn't provide build_association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

A TimeLog can either be Invoiced or not, and an Invoice contains many TimeLogs. Our database can't have nullable foreign keys, so we're using a join model. The code:

```
class TimeLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :invoices_time_logs
  has_one :invoice, through: :invoices_time_logs
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices_time_logss
  has_many :time_logs, through: :invoices_time_logss
end

class InvoicesTimeLogs
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :time_log
end
```

Invoice.first.time_logs.build works fine, but TimeLog.first.build_invoice gives

> NoMethodError: undefined method `build_invoice' for
>   #<TimeLog:0x4acd588>

Isn't has_one supposed to make the build_association method available?

Update:

I've made a sample repo for this question: [build_assocation_test](https://github.com/shlevy/build_association_test). To see the problem, clone the repo, install the bundle, run the migrations (or load the schema), and then in a rails console:

```
Invoice.create
Invoice.first.time_logs.build
TimeLog.create
TimeLog.first.build_invoice
```

Comment: can you confirm you have at least 1 Timelog in your DB? Or post the full NoMethodError error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a typo.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices_time_logss
  has_many :time_logs, through: :invoices_time_logss
end
```

should be...

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices_time_logs
  has_many :time_logs, through: :invoices_time_logs
end
```

no?

Comment: I don't see a difference between those. And I'm pretty sure my Invoice class is set up right, since I can do Invoice.time_logs.build and it works properly

Comment: I typo'd your typo :)  Check again, sorry.

Comment: Huh, weird, I dunno maybe it works, just looks weird to me.  I'll check it out when I get to work in a bit.